# character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df3) with with some values.

One of these values is the daedlines.

The data of this value is something like the following:

```
deadline
1419397140
1418994978
1419984000
1418702400
```

They are days and I want to convert the to using this:

```
df3$deadline <- as.POSIXct(df3$deadline, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Generally it was worked for me with other dataframes from other files.

However with this it gives me back this error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your data is not numeric, but probably factors. This is likely a problem that should be solved during data import.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might be that you have a character or factor, and it's expecting a numeric vector for conversion from unix time :

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(df3$deadline)),origin="1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 5):

As a suggestion for future debugging, you  can check your parameter type by using

```
class(df3$deadline)
```

and making sure you are passing the correct type to as.POSIXlt().

From the help menu for asPOSIX*():

> Character input is first converted to class '"POSIXlt"' by
>   'strptime': numeric input is first converted to '"POSIXct"'.  Any
>   conversion that needs to go between the two date-time classes
>   requires a time zone: conversion from '"POSIXlt"' to '"POSIXct"'
>   will validate times in the selected time zone.