# Error converting string feature to numeric in Azure ML studio

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

`QuotedPremium` column is a string feature so I need to convert it to numeric value in order to use algorithm.

[image]

So, for that I am using Edit Metadata module, where I specify data type to be converted is `Floating Point`.

After I run it - I got an error:

```
Could not convert type System.String to type System.Double, inner exception message: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: If your source dataset has numbers handled as text, you must change them to a numeric data type before using math operations. I assume that there is not all numeric data type of your source data ,such as the first value : NULL. But I'm not sure.

Comment: There couldn't be NULL values in your column. First clear the missing data and perform edit metadata step.

Comment: Thanks. So I supposed to be able to substitute NULL's in my data using ML studio? Which module should I use for that?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you must change column where numbers are handled as text to numeric type data and it shouldn't have any null values. Now answering the question of how to substitute NULL's in data using ML studio and converting to numeric type.

**Substitute NULL's in data**

Use `Execute R Script` module for that, and add this code in it.

```
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1); # class: data.frame
dataset1[dataset1 == "NULL"] = 0; # Wherever cell's value is "NULL", replace it with 0
maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1"); # return the modified data.frame
```

Image for same:
[image]

**Convert to numeric data**

As you have added in your answer, this can be done using the `Edit Metadata` module.

Comment: I get the error: ``` character string is not in a standard unambiguous format ``` (Using the R Script)

What would you suggest here?

Comment: Hi @kierandes not sure if its something related to the R script component. As according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105369/character-string-is-not-in-a-standard-unambiguous-format it maybe the case that if there is datetime value in string format in dataset and the conversion to datetime object is failing because its not able to figure out the format. Will you be able to share part of the script and dataset of what you are trying to do?