# Selecting Columns in Microsoft Azure ML Studio Dataset alters the variable type

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to select some columns from a dataset in Microsoft Azure ML Studio.
My dataset column is a decimal at first.
[image]
After I pass the data through a "Select Column in Dataset" asset, the same column becomes a string, instead of remaining decimal.
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Not able to find exact reason for why decimal datatype is changing to string data type after Select Columns.

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787973) by [akashperfect](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2978616/akashperfect) to similar type of question, Check if there are any NULL values. There couldn't be NULL values in your column. First clear the missing data and perform edit metadata step.

[image]

If this does not resolve your issue, then you can Create a support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/)

Comment: I was able to do the trick with 
1. CLEAN MISSING DATA (on only columns I wanted then REMOVE ENTIRE ROW if missing)
2. EDIT MEDATADA (for my columns).

Comment: @AndreiIovan, If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.